# In the python console how to print all of elements out in a list

Tags: python, list, element

I want to find an element in a list. I am using this bit code

```
for i, j in enumerate(N[1].mismatch):
    if j == -8090.99422495:
        print i
```

When I'm doing this I do not get any errors, neither is anything printed out in the console. I know that this value is contained in the list `N[1].mismatch`. When I print the list this is what i get and we see that the value is contained in the list.

```
array([-8090.99422495, -7931.6931084 , -7840.25122374, ..., -4500.01204242,
       -3191.63959231, -2526.82103341])
```

Comment: Sometimes floating point comparison does not work as well as expected. Try converting everything to string then doing your comparison

Comment: is `N[1]` a numpy array? I'm not familiar with a `mismatch` method on lists.